# ImportError: Module use of python27.dll conflicts with this version of Python

Tags: python

Im currently trying to make a python script for Harris Corner Detection, and I keep getting this error no matter what other articles/fixes I find. Thanks for any help you can give.

Edit: Its the first line of the code that gives the error

Code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

filename = 'chessboard.jpg'
img = cv2.imread(filename)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

gray = np.float32(gray)
dst = cv2.cornerHarris(gray,2,3,0.04)

#result is dilated for marking the corners, not important
dst = cv2.dilate(dst,None)

# Threshold for an optimal value, it may vary depending on the image.
img[dst>0.01*dst.max()]=[0,0,255]

cv2.imshow('dst',img)
if cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xff == 27:
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: What version of python do you run?

Comment: Im running 2.7, 3.4 and 3.2 And the CV2 needs 2.7

Comment: And you're getting this error no matter which python version you run?

Comment: Yes. Ive tested all of them

Comment: Is your CV2 32bit or 64bit, conflicts with python version.

Comment: @InnecticGaming Did you find a way to fix the error?

Comment: @DanielKleinstein Actually, no I never did. I really had just given up.

Comment: solved it by uninstalled all python version + the module clean regedit, reinstalled python (using default settings) and then the module (win32clipboard in my case).

Comment: I had this problem when building and using a python module for Python3, but CMAKE configured itself to use Python27 for wrapping. Manually updated Cmake and that fixed it

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue occur also.  In my environment settings I had a variable PYTHONPATH pointing to the directory of my Python 2.7 version of cv2.pyd.  Updating this to the Python 3.4 version of the cv2.pyd directory fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have install opencv 2.4.x for windows and copy cv2.pyd to conda home.This works for python2.7, but for python3.x, you can try install opencv follow these step:

1 Activate python3 env and run  `anaconda search -t conda opencv` in command-line,then you will get a table,chose one of them from `name` column.

2 Then like `anaconda show conda-forge/opencv` .

3 Last you will find advice and just follow it:

```
To install this package with conda run:
     conda install --channel https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge opencv
```