# "Module use of python34.dll conflicts with this version of Python"

Tags: pyside, python-3.4, maya, pyqt5, qtwidgets

My knowledge of Python is still pretty basic, and I am only now trying to wrap my head around how to use / call libraries from within Maya. (Because I need to create a basic UI from QT Designer and have it be opened in Maya after converting it to a .py file)

After I learned to properly convert a .ui to a .py, I now get this error in Maya

> "Module use of python34.dll conflicts with this version of Python"

I tried following what was said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28826410/importerror-module-use-of-python27-dll-conflicts-with-this-version-of-python) and [here](http://forums.autodesk.com/t5/maya-forum/maya-2015-startup-error-python-conflicting/td-p/5509095), but even then - after setting these environment variables...

> PYTHONHOME = C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2016\bin\maya.exe
>
> PYTHONPATH = C:\Python34

... I a still unable to run a basic .py file. In fact - as long as the PYTHONHOME variable is in effect, Python from within Maya no longer does anything.

This code below is the resulting python file that I got from converting the .ui file that I saved out of QT Designer.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'test.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.4.1
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(400, 300)
        self.buttonBox = QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox(Dialog)
        self.buttonBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 240, 341, 32))
        self.buttonBox.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.buttonBox.setStandardButtons(QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel|QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Ok)
        self.buttonBox.setObjectName("buttonBox")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        self.buttonBox.accepted.connect(Dialog.accept)
        self.buttonBox.rejected.connect(Dialog.reject)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I've come across some different online notes that advised the use of PySide, and after trying to use:

```
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *
```

I still couldn't test if this works, because apparently QtWidgets isn't a module?

I'm pretty lost. The bigger picture is that I just want to be able to run a ui created from QT Designer from Maya's script editor. I have no idea where to begin with learning about libraries. Would anyone here be kind enough to give some advice?

Additional info:

```
I am using Maya 2016, running on a Windows 10 64 bit OS.
I also have a Python 2.7 in my C: drive 
And I am using PyQt5-5.4.1-gpl-Py3.4-Qt5.4.1-x64
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3):

Maya's python interpreter is in the 2.7 series (or 2.6 for Maya 2013 and earlier). Your `PYTHONPATH` is pointing at a python 3.4 install. You also want to make sure that if your Python 3.4 is in `PATH` it comes later than the maya python install location.  This is all to makes sure that Maya doesn't get confused and try to run python 3 code or dlls which it cannot handle.

Also, maya 2016 is running on PyQT4.   Maya 2017 runs on PyQT5.  So you'll probably want to use a PyQT4 version of designer

Related:

- [UIC / PyQT4 example](http://www.chrisevans3d.com/pub_blog/pyqt4-uic-module-example/)
- [using UIC files in Maya pyQT 4](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/maya/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/Maya/files/GUID-FAD0F6CC-15D0-4489-9372-028146B70F49-htm.html)
- [re: 2017/QT5](https://fredrikaverpil.github.io/2016/07/25/dealing-with-maya-2017-and-pyside2/)

Comment: **Thank you @theodox**

Took your advice and got a copy of qt4 (PyQt4-4.10-gpl-Py2.7-Qt4.8.4-x64). I uninstalled python 3.4 (kept 2.7) and made sure that I cleared the paths.I copied pyQT4 folder into the maya site Packages folder, I even included sip.pyd which I got from (WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.7) and placed it in the same folder.

Checked the path, made sure that c:\Python27 was entered last, and created a PYTHONPATH variable that aslo points to c:\Python27.
-- but now I get this --
`ImportError: file <maya console> line 12: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.`

Comment: Maya includes PyQT4  -- you don't need to add it!  And you should probably set your PYTHONPATH to point at the maya python location